# Image of a line under Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Let $T$ be a Mobius transformation such that $T(0)=\alpha$, $T(\alpha)=0$ and $T(\infty)=-\alpha$, where $\alpha = (-1+i)/\sqrt 2$. Let $L$ dnotes the straight line passing through origin with slope $-1$ and $C$ denotes the unit circle centered at origin. Then which are true ?

(A) $T$ maps $L$ to a straight line.

(B) $T$ maps $L$ to a circle.

(C) $T^{-1}$ maps $C$ to a straight line.

(D) $T^{-1}$ maps $C$ to a circle.

Using cross ratio we get the Mobius transformation is $$z=-\alpha \frac{w-\alpha}{w+\alpha}$$

where, $w:=T(z)$.

From this, equating real and imaginary parts I can solve the problem. But that is too laborious. **Does there any shorter way to solve this problem ?**

But

Comment: Given any $3$ distinct points $\{a,b,c\}$, there exists exactly one circle (or line) passing trough them. If $T$ maps $\{a,b,c\}$ to $\{T(a), T(b), T(c)\}$, then $T$ will map the line (or circle) passing trough   $\{a,b,c\}$  to the line (or circle) passing trough $\{T(a), T(b), T(c)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Möbius transformation maps every [line or circle] to some [line or circle].

$T^{-1}$ maps $\alpha,0,-\alpha\in L$ to $0,\alpha,\infty\in L$ hence $T^{-1}(L)=L,$ so A is true ($T(L)=L$) hence B is false.

$T^{-1}$ maps $-\alpha\in C$ to $\infty,$ so D is false hence C is true.